# On ubuntu 12.04, what file has the systemwide list of gem sources for rubygems 1.9.1

Tags: ubuntu, puppet, rubygems

I need to deploy a gem from a custom gem source to my ubuntu 12.04 servers that are managed by puppet. In the puppet class, I will put the command that adds our custom gem server to the gem sources, it's as easy as running `gem sources -a <hostname or ip>`.

The convention in our puppet library, when using execs, is to always put the name of the file that is created by the command, so the exec is not repeated redundantly, but I can't find which file on the system is created by this command.

Answer (score 0):

The system wide gem sources are stored in /etc/gemrc.